# How to get the angle of an image ? (IOS)

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, rotation, angle, degrees

Ok, so I rotated an image by 25 degrees like this :

```
MyImage.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(25);
```

Now I want to rotate the image again by 25 more degrees (50 degrees in total)

So my question is, How do I rotate X more degrees an image ?

If you have any other way to rotate an image or better way please include your code.

Comment: Apply an additional transform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to know the current angle! Instead of setting the `affineTransform`, which is only a shortcut, apply an actual 3D transform. Now you can call `CATransform3DRotate`, which rotates an existing transform — and thus is additive.